# Selecting records containing an emoji or counting emoji in text in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table in SQL Server 2014 (v12.0.6329.1) with a `NVARCHAR` column that contains text. It's possible that the column contains emoji characters. How can I select or differentiate records that contain at least one emoji?

Bonus points: how can I COUNT the number of emojis in each text?

Example data:

[image]

Ideally, I'd like to make a field that counts the number of emoji, but I'd settle for just being able to tell if there's an emoji at all.

Answer (score 1):

This query will do it

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET NumOfEmojis = (len(yourcolumn) - len(replace(CAST( yourcolumn AS VARCHAR(MAX)), '?????', '')))/5
```

The explanation is that when you convert your text to `VARCHAR(MAX)` the existing emojis in your text will adopt the form ????? (five question marks).
As T-SQL doesn't have a function to count occurrences of a string the fastest way AFAIK is to delete them and calculate:

```
((length of original string) - (length of string without ?????)) / 5
```

Comment: Does this still work? On SEDE (Stackoverflow's TSQL data site), It doesn't appear to calculate the number correctly.